# Can Docker-Swarm run in fail-over-mode only?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am facing a situation, where I need to run about 100 different applications in Docker containers. It is not reasonable to run all 100 containers on one hardware, so I need to spread the applications over several machines.
As far as I understood, docker-swarm is for scaling only, which means when I run my containers in a swarm, than all 100 containers will automatically be deployed and started on every node of my docker-swarm. But this is not what I am searching for. I want to split the applications and for example run 50 on node1 and 50 on node2.

**Question 1:**
Is there a way to configure docker-swarm in a way, where my applications will be automatically dispatched on the node which has the most idling resources?

**Question 2:**
Is there a kind of fail-over-mode in docker swarm which can stop a container on one node and try to start it on on another in case something goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all 100 containers will automatically be deployed and started on every node of my docker-swarm

This is not true. When you deploy 100 containers in a swarm, the containers will be distributed on the available nodes in the swarm. You will mostly get an even distribution of containers on all nodes.

> Question 1: Is there a way to configure docker-swarm in a way, where my applications will be automatically dispatched on the node which has the most idling resources?

Docker swarm does not check the available resources (memory, cpu ...) available on the nodes before deploying a container on it. The distribution of containers is balanced per nodes, without taking into account the availability of resources on each node.

You can however build a strategy of distributing container on the nodes. You can use [placement constraints](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#placement) were you can restrict where a container can be deployed. You can label nodes having a lot of resources and restrict some heavy containers to only run on these nodes.

> Question 2: Is there a kind of fail-over-mode in docker swarm which can stop a container on one node and try to start it on on another in case something goes wrong?

If a container crashes, docker swarm will ensure that a new container is started. Again, the decision of what node to deploy the new container on cannot be predetermined.

Comment: Does this mean, that the scale factor of a service will not start the same number of instances on each node? So at least the number of instances defined by the scale-factor, will be even distributed on my nodes? E.g. if I have 4 Nodes and  scale-factor for one service is set to 2, in summary exactly 2 containers will run on too of my 4 nodes?

Comment: @Ralph Yes, that is true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have read the [Swarm mode key concepts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/) before.